# A proof in Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

In http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Cyclic_Group_is_Cyclic

> However, m was the smallest positive integer such that $a^m \in H$ and $0 \leq r < m$, so $r=0$.

I don't understand this, so if $m = 4$, what stops $r$ from being say $2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line immediately preceding that in the proof shows that $a^r\in H$. Since $m$ is the *smallest* positive integer such that $a^m\in H$, $r$ cannot be positive, else it would be a positive integer smaller than $m$ such that $a^r\in H$. So necessarily $r=0$.

Comment: Oh okay right, forgot about that

Comment: Why did they start the proof with $m$ as the smallest power in the first place? Why doesn't any arbitrary $m$ work?

Comment: @Sizz It is the least such power of $a$ which generates the subgroup $H$. The hope is show that any arbitrary element of $H$ is a product of this least power of $a$ in $H$.

Comment: But why choose the smallest power is my question.

Comment: @sizz The aim to show $H$ is cyclic, and to do this, you need to show $H$ is generated by a single element. The least power of $a$ is one such generator. An arbitrary power of $a$ may not be a generator. For example, if you had chosen $2m$ instead, $\langle a^{2m}\rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $H$. For example, if $H=\{a^m, a^{2m},a^{3m},a^{4m}=e\}$, then $\langle a^{2m}\rangle=\{e,a^{2m}\}$. So you wouldn't necessarily be able to conclude $H$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was shown before that $r\in S\cup\{0\}$ with $S:=\{n\in \mathbb N\mid a^n\in H\}$. Therefore, $r<\min S$ implies $r=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a^r = \left({a^m}\right)^{-q} a^n\in H$, while "$m$ was the smallest positive integer".